# LIKE in Linq to SQL

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a method that needs to accept an array of country names, and return a list of records that  match one of those country names. I'm trying this

```
Public Shared Function GetConcessions(ByVal Countries As String()) As IEnumerable
    Dim CountryList As String = Utility.JoinArray(Countries) ' turns string array into comma-separated string
    Return (From t In New Db().Concessions _
                    Where CountryList Like t.Country _
                    Select t.ConcessionID, t.Title, t.Country)
End Function
```

but I get this error

```
  *Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the LIKE method
```

In plain SQL, this would be simple:

```
 Select ConcessionID,Title from Concessions c where @CountryList like '%' + c.Country + '%'
```

How can I achieve this result in Linq to SQL?

#### Edit (clarification)

I get the same message with string.Contains. It would be fine with

```
t.Country.contains(CountryList)
```

but I need

```
CountryList.contains(t.Country)
```

and that throws the same error I listed above.

Comment: I realised after reading more carefully that my answer was no good :)

Comment: Accepted answer is not best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is construct a List from Countries and use

```
List<string> ListOfCountries = new List(Countries)

...ListOfCountries.Contains(t.Country)
```

This would translate into

```
t.Country IN ('yyy','zzz',...)
```

Please excuse my C#-ishness..

Answer (score 9):

You can use SqlMethods.Like

e.g.

```
Where SqlMethods.Like(t.country, "%Sweden%")
```

Comment: very nice when u need to put the database field on the right side :)