# How to use Contains() in my join

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, contains

I am trying to get my linq query to replicate my t-sql but I am lost.

```
SELECT *
FROM BaiDetail INNER JOIN
     BaiDetailMap ON BaiDetail.DetailText 
     LIKE '%' + BaiDetailMap.BaiDetailMapSearchText +'%'
```

This is what I have so far... but no go

```
from det in Source
from map in Map
where det.DetailText.Contains(map.SearchText)
select new {det, map}
```

Error Message:

Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.Contains method.

Comment: take a look at this one, it may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192126/like-in-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from det in Source
from map in Map
where SqlMethods.Like(map.DetailText, "%" + map.SearchText + "%"))
select new {det, map}
```

Comment: Won't work : string.Format can only be evaluated locally, not in the database